# Retrofit and MediaWIkiAPI, How to get page content in a strange key name in json?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, mediawiki

I'm newbie in Android - kotlin, retrofit, rxjava - and building the 'data class' to use in retrofit to get pages in mediawiki.

**my code :**

```
data class  WikiArticleResult (val result : List<WikiArticleModel>)
data class  WikiArticleModel (val revid: Int,
                          @SerializedName("pageid") val id: Int,
                          @SerializedName("title") val titleContent: String,
                          @SerializedName("text") val contentHtml: List<ContentWikiPage>,
                          val summary: String
                    )
data class ContentWikiPage (val Content: String, val images: List<ImagesWiki> )

data class ImagesWiki (val images: String)
```

The MediaWiki API Json example :

```
api.php?action=parse&format=json&pageid=30&prop=text&utf8=1
```

results:

```
{
"parse": {
"title": "Article Title in MediaWiki Example",
"pageid": 30,
"text": {
  "*": "<table align=\"center\" class=\"noprint\" style=\"width:75%; margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse; background: #fbfbfb; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-left: 15px solid black;\">\n<tr>\n<td width=\"10%\" align=\"center\">\n<div style=\"width:50px;\"><a href=\"/wikiprf/index.php/Arquivo:Ato_Normativo.png\" class=\"image\"><img alt=\"Ato Normativo.png\" src=\"/wikiprf/images/thumb/8/88/Ato_Normativo.png/62px-Ato_Normativo.png\" width=\"62\" height=\"62\" srcset=\"/w ......
  }
 }
}
```

**The problem::**

This **"*"** couldn't be a variable name (*), but retrofit demand me to use a property as the same name as the key in json array. 
How do I do do get the page content in mediawiki api in retrofit (Android, Kotlin) ?

Comment: Please paste you full url so that i can see the api response

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7BProject:Sandbox%7D%7D&contentmodel=wikitext @pankajyadav

Comment: That's a example. I can't post exactly URL of my own mediawiki because enterprise politics doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't possibly know the name, the property cannot be mapped to a named field but to a Dictionary or Map type. Assuming you're using Gson as a converter with your Retrofit, a good git would be `JsonObject` but you should explore `JsonElement` also. You will have to then loop through the keys (*'s) to find your data.

To see how to configure Gson or any other converter see the *Retrofit Configuration* section here https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Gson javadoc is here: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5

Note you can fine-tune your serialization process to match your needs with a custom deserializer. More on this here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md